# Performance Issue - Taking too much time while writing huge csv file at unix box in java , Interact with MYSQL DB to do cross check for each record

Tags: java, mysql, performance, unix, jdbc

My Java application read huge csv file (size around 6-7 mb, Having 50k to 60k records), In between connect to mysql db for each record to do cross check (having only select query) and perform some operation, write all records in tmp csv file. But here issue is that this process taking around 6-7 hours to write tmp file ?

Sample Code -

```
public static void updateTransactionCsvFiles(String inputFilePath , String existingFileName,File outputFolder,File archiveFolder,String tpName) throws IOException {

     File inputFile = new File(inputFilePath);
     Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new   FileInputStream(inputFile), charset));
     CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(in, '|','"');
     List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();

    File newFile = new File("tmp.csv");
               BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(newFile), charset),32768);
               CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(bw, '|',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); // JDBC Type4
       connection =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+dbhostname+"/db",dbusername,dbpassword);
    }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    for(int row=0 ; row < csvBody.listSize; row++){
        String eachRecord[]= csvBody.get(row);
         String array[]= csvBody.get(row);
         array = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1); //create new array from old array and allocate three more element
        array[array.length - 1] = "brandName";
         csvBody.remove(row);
         csvBody.add(row, array);


        String customerId = eachRecord[3];
        List tpList = new ArrayList();
        tpList.add("100");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for( int i = 0 ; i < tpList.size(); i++ ) {
                    builder.append("?,");
                }           

      String query = "select customer_id from customer where client_id IN " + 
      "(" 
                             + builder.deleteCharAt( builder.length() -1 ).toString() + ")"+" and customer_id = ? "; 
       PreparedStatement pstmt =connection.prepareStatement(query); 
           pstmt.setObject(index,customerId);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
           String pid ="";      
           while(rs.next()){
                    pid=rs.getInt(3);
                }

             csvBody.get(row)[4] = pid;            


            pstmt =con.prepareStatement(""SELECT status, senttime, process_id FROM feed WHERE customer_id = ? and sent_time =(select MAX(senttime) FROM feeds WHERE customer_id = ? ) "");
       pstmt.setObject(1,customerId);
        pstmt.setObject(2,customerId);
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
            feedstatus = rs.getString(1);
            senttime = rs.getTimestamp(2);
            processid =rs.getInt(3);
        }
               csvBody.get(row)[6] = feedstatus;  
                rs.close(); 
                pstmt.close();
      }

        writer.writeAll(csvBody); // write all records in to the file.
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        csvBody.clear();
        csvBody = null;
        reader.close();
    }
```

Comment: I have noticed that when this code deploy at QA environment, process takes 15-20 minutes to complete. But while deploy same code at production environment same process take 6-7 hours As prod has huge customer data. :(  It seems max time consume at the time of DB(mysql) interaction as using 2-3 select queries to perform some validation.

Comment: select customer_id from customer_id where id_value in (100,200); taking too much time at prod env.

Comment: Should I go with hibernate instead of jdbc to cache the output of these multiple queries (select statement ), So that It will not hit database every time to fetch the result ? OR Should I go with stored procedures (Callable stmt )? please suggest if any other solution need to be implemented to reduce the process time.

Comment: Or Do I need to do Query optimization if yes then how ? :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making the following changes:

- There is no need to read all the lines of file at once and process. Instead, you can read it line by line, execute the query and write it to file. That's exactly how `BufferedReader` should be used.
- You are using `csvBody.remove(row);` and `csvBody.add(row, array);` which is not a good practice. We should not be modifying the collection that is being iterated.
- You don't need to create a new `PreparedStatement` object for every iteration. You can declare it outside of `for` loop and execute it in every iteration by setting the parameters.
- `csvBody.clear();` is not required as we won't be reading all the lines.
- You might want to add an index on `client_id` column if there isn't one already.

Below is a example of how to read a huge csv file line by line:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new   FileInputStream(inputFile), charset));
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(in, '|','"');

String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
//Process line
}
```

Comment: I have taken out all PreparedStatement query from for loop and initialize all prepared statement before the loop but doesn't see any performance improvement.  :(

Comment: You need to add the loop that processes the file line by line, instead of reading everything into list. That should improve the performance significantly.

Comment: I have tried to loop that process the file line by line also but now performance is decreased , No improvement even time elapsed increased  :(

Comment: It seems application consume max time when application interact with prod data base as it has huge data.

Comment: You are querying on `client id`, does the table have any index on that column? If not, can you try adding one?

Comment: Thanks a lot Darshan.it works fine After Adding the new index ,  Below changes done on table. ALTER TABLE `customer` ADD INDEX clientid_index (`client_id`);